# Does every android phone has download app installed by default on their phone?

Tags: android, android-package-managers

After clicking on a button I would like to start the default Download application. Will this work on every phone or at least on the majority of the phones?

Thanks.

Comment: Unless user has uninstalled it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All phones have a certain amount of default unremovable undeactivatable apps. Those include:

- Download overview
- The OS
- The launcher
- The gallery
- The video player
- SMS, phone, contacts
- Google Play
- Settings

All of those are overridable, but they cannot be removed or deactivated but their features can be overriden by other apps. The exception is Google Play and Settings. It cannot be overriden and it cannot be uninstalled or deactivated.

There are also a lot of deactivatable but uninstallable apps. Those include a lot of google applications like Google Chrome, gmail, google search and so on.

In addition each phone comes with its own set of apps that cannot be uninstalled. Samsung has S Health, S planner and more. These apps are not required for anything and that is why they are deactivatable. They are still bloatware and therefore cannot be **uninstalled**. Every single phone ever made has the download app installed. Some times it is controlled by the OS and in some cases it has been overriden by the phone manufacturer.